# build android and get apt with ionic and cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i wanna get apk with this command in ionic 
IONIC BUILD ANDROID

but when i run this,my serve

```html
root@mail:~/bbapp/bb# ionic build android
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Running command: /root/bbapp/bb/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /root/bbapp/bb
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /root/bbapp/bb/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /root/bbapp/bb/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /root/bbapp/bb/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Comment: see this error : it is clear ;) [Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]

Comment: @aorfevre how i can do this???please say clear :)

Answer (score 0):

See [official ionic doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html), I quote :

> Android SDK
>
> Installing the Android SDK is also necessary. The Android SDK provides
>   you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test,
>   and debug apps for Android.
>
> Cordova requires the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to be set. This
>   should point to the [ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk directory (for
>   example c:\android\android-sdk).
>
> Next, update your PATH to include the tools/ and platform-tools/
>   folder in that folder. So, using ANDROID_HOME, you would add both
>   %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools.

Then, updating environment variables depends on your system.
Commands are different for windows / unix

Comment: i am trying 10 hours,but i can't get result.can  you do this for me??i sent server details for you :)

Comment: This is not a good way to do it asking for people to do your job. We help and guide, but I won't do it for you. If i did it, you will not learn anything !

Comment: @aorefvre please guide me more